# Correction of labelling bias using the labeler identity as a feature

Tags: classification, bias, labeling

Suppose I have a dataset labeled by multiple analysts.
I assume that each analyst has some bias in his labeling.
Is there any literature on reducing the bias effect on the general model by using the analyst name?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any answer yet so I am answering the best I can. Assume that I have a function creating the prediction of the labeled data considering the features $\vec{x}$ and the analyst $a$ $$f(\vec{x}, a)\sim S(\vec{x})+b(a)+F(0,\sigma)$$ Another function neglects the analyst and takes his effect as noise is distributed by $$f_b(\vec{x})\sim S(\vec{x})+F(0,\sigma+\sigma_b)$$ We might create a new correction function $$g(\vec{x},a)=f_b(\vec{x})-f(\vec{x}, a)\sim b(a)+F(0,2\sigma+\sigma_b)$$ Substitute into the original estimation provides $$\widetilde{f}(\vec{x},a)=f(\vec{x},a)-g(\vec{x},a)\sim S(\vec{x})+F(0,3\sigma)$$ The condition of improving the estimation by using the correction factor is $Var\left[f_b\right]<Var\left[\widetilde{f}\right]$, leading to $\sigma_b>2\sigma$.

I hope it makes sense. Please feel free to suggest corrections or point me to a reference.